# Não existem disposítivos compatíveis ao publicar no Google Play

Tags: android, deploy, google-play

Estou com um problema na hora de publicar meu App na google play. Não aparecem dispositivos compativeis quando envio o APK, sendo que no desenvolvimento ele funcionou normal em vários celulares (Ex. Galaxy star, Galaxy gran dual, Motorola moto g2)

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="br.com.MeuApp" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="br.com.MeuApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<permission
    android:name="br.com.MeuApp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_ico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Actionbartema" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.Splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LaboratoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_laboratory"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.CustomerActivity"
        android:label="@string/area_cliente"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ExamResultActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_exam_result"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.CustomerActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.CustomerActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.ListActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.ListActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.PartnersActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_partners"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.PartnersActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ServicesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_services"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.ServiceListActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_service_list"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.ServicesActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.ServicesActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.PartnesDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_partnes_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.PartnersActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.PartnersActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.DetailServiceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_servicet"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.ServiceListActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.ServiceListActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Activities.MyProfileActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_my_profile"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activities.CustomerActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="br.com.MeuApp.Activities.CustomerActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

segue uma imagem do meu console
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o Android Studio, vou postar tambem meu arquivo: build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   android {
      compileSdkVersion 22
      buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

      defaultConfig {
         applicationId "br.com.MeuApp"
         minSdkVersion 13
         targetSdkVersion 22
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
      }
      signingConfigs {
         release {
           storeFile file("/Users/fernando/chave.jks")
           storePassword "senha"
           keyAlias "MeuApp"
           keyPassword "senha"
         }
      }
      buildTypes {
         release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
      }
   }
   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
      provided 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.6'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
      compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
      compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
      compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
      compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'
      compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
      compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.6'
      compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.1'
   }
```

Comment: ao utilizar o comando jarsigner -verbose -verify -keystore ~/chave.jks my-app.apk recebi o seguinte retorno: `this jar contains signatures that not include a timestamp. without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2040-09-16) or after any future revocation date.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muitas tentativas eu descobri o erro. O problema era nessa lib que provavelmente não é compatível com os termos da Google. E eu usei ela pra gerar uma string base64. mas depois descobri como fazer sem utilizar essa lib.

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.6'
```